# How does IP prevent infinite loops?

Tags: networking, ip

Question on a review:

If a packet is mistakenly routed in a closed loop among a number of machines, it could theoretically loop in the network forever. How does IP ensure that this cannot happen for Internet Packets?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is such thing as [TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live). You should perform basic internet search before posting a question.

Comment: And you should avoid chastising people in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did search it, pretty close to what the title of my question was.